# Reading data from tr with an id inside the tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I am trying to read data from input field inside "td" with an id inside the "tbody"

The html structure is like this:

```
    <tbody id="tbody1">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="bacthNo" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
      </td>      
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="text" id="bacthNo" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
      </td>
   </tr>  
</tbody>
<tbody id="tbody2">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="bacthNo" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
      </td>      
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="text" id="bacthNo" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
      </td>
   </tr>  
</tbody>
```

Here the "tbody" id is changing dynamically and tr can be in between 1 to 10 for each "tbody".

What i want is to read all the data of "bacthNo","location" and "qty" for each tbody and push into an array on form submit. I had tried several approach but not able to fetch data from this complicated form.

Kindly Help.

Comment: don't use increasing `id` for `<tbody>`. simply use same class for each tbody and then use `.each` and get everything. (through id it can be done also, but a bit complex code needed)

Comment: Can you give me same code sample? That would help me

Answer (score 2):

apply class to all of your fields and then access using `each` function of `jquery` like this

```
  <tr>
  <td>
     <input type="text" id="bacthNo" class="bacthNo form-control md-has-value" required="">
  </td>
  <td>
     <input type="text" id="location" class="location form-control md-has-value" required="">
  </td>
  <td>
     <input type="text" id="qty" class="qty form-control md-has-value" required="">
  </td>
```

```
 $('#tbody1').find('tr').each(function () {
             var eachtr = $(this);
            eachtr.find('.bacthNo').val();
            eachtr.find('.location').val();
            eachtr.find('.qty').val();
           //get your all fields
}
```

for example see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fCpc6/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the tbody will also change dynamically. How to read data from all the tbody at a single iteration?

Comment: then apply class to all tbody and make each fun for all tbody from table  $('#yourtableid').find('.tbodyclass').each(function () {}); like this

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```js
       document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            var _rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tr');                
        //depending on your markup you could use also: 
        // var _rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
        // var _rows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
       //or THE WORST CASE if you cannot really change your html:
       //document.querySelectorAll('tbody[id*="tbody"] tr');
            _rows.forEach(function (row) {
                var _bacthNo = row.querySelector('#bacthNo');
                var _location  = row.querySelector('#location');
                var _qty  = row.querySelector('#qty');

                console.log(_bacthNo.value)
                console.log(_location.value)
                console.log(_qty.value)
            });
        });
```

```html
 <table>

        <tbody id="tbody1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="bacthNo" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="bacthNo" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="tbody2">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="bacthNo" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="bacthNo" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#tblOne > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
alert($(this).find("td:first>input").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblOne">
<tbody id="tbody1">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="bacthNo" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
      </td>      
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="text" id="bacthNo" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
      </td>
   </tr>  
</tbody>
<tbody id="tbody2">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="bacthNo" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control md-has-value" required="">
      </td>      
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="text" id="bacthNo" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control md-has-value" required="" value="0">
      </td>
   </tr>  
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if you dont want to have the id in table then just use selector "table > tbody  > tr"

Comment: you could use class attribute and select with it, otherwise use nth-child selector   
alert("batch "+$(this).find("td:first>input").val());
alert("Location "+$(this).find("td:nth-child(2)>input").val());
alert("Qty "+$(this).find("td:nth-child(3)>input").val());